# SwitchCompat showing box outline and background on certain devices

Tags: android, android-layout, switchcompat

Please take a look at the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFC7.png).

This is my XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:theme="@style/MySwitch" />
```

This is my style:

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switchInactiveThumbColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I have tested it on Nexus 5, Nexus 6P, Nexus 5X and a number of Samsung devices. It works fine on them. But it shows these boxes in **Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge** and **HTC One M9 Plus**. How can I fix this?